# QGIS Raster Calculator syntax

Tags: raster, raster-calculator, syntax

I have tried this several different ways and get lots of NaN.

I need to specify that in my raster 'test1', I want a certain set of values to equal 1 and the rest to equal zero. For instance, I want 1, 42, and 102 to equal 1 and the rest to equal zero.

I have tried:

```
"test1@1" = 1 OR "test1@1" = 42 OR "test1@1" = 102
```

as well a few other options.

Unfortunately, there seem to be no existing syntax guidelines for the raster calculator (if you know of some, please send me a link).

How do I make this work?

Comment: Have you tried putting your logical statements in brackets (e.g. "("test1@1= 1”) OR..."). Additionally, you could also try just multiplying your statements by 1 and adding them instead of using logical OR.

Comment: Yes, I have tried all of those options. All result in a new layer with all values = NaN.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried an equivalent syntax for my raster (200 x 200 and random values between 1 and 102):

```
"random_raster@1" = 1 OR "random_raster@1" = 42 OR "random_raster@1" = 102
```

and it works; as it could be see at the next image ('Zoom In' in a reduced area of output raster **out3.tif** to verify, with 'Value Tool' plugin, the values obtained).

[image]

In your case, it should work too.

Comment: The created raster on mine only has undefined values, so nothing shows up.

It might be an issue of versions. I have the latest version (Wien) and it looks like you are running Lyon. I can't find any bug reports of this particular issue online though.

Comment: I should also clarify that having just the first one alone "test1@1" = 1 works just fine.